# No current query in data reader MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database, syntax

```
mscon.Open();
mscom = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cbin_tbl WHERE cb_id=(SELECT MAX(cb_id) FROM cbin_tbl)", mscon);
MySqlDataReader msmdr1 = mscom.ExecuteReader();
while (msmdr1.Read())
{ 
   barcode = msmdr.GetString("cb_id"); 
}
mscon.Close();
```

IM A BEGINNER HERE AND HELP ME ON THIS MYSQL SYNTAX :D THANKS

Answer (score 0):

[`GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring) takes `int` as a parameter which is *zero-based* column number, not `string`.

If your sql is fine, you need to get the first column as `GetString(0)` and second column as `GetString(1)` etc.. If it is not, you can change your query as;

```
mscom = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cbin_tbl order by cb_id desc limit 1");
```

which seems identical to me.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. And also the other error that i saw is my MySqlDataReader msmdr1 = mscom.ExecuteReader();  AND MY 
   barcode = msmdr.GetString("cb_id");